# Identify duplicate values distinguished by second variable

Tags: r, duplicates, match, unique

I'm working with a `data.frame ("hi")` that outlines health insurance plans for counties across the US. For *each* plan there is a row with `State` and `County` columns as well as information regarding the plan itself (premium, deductible, etc).

As part of my analysis, I would like to tie this `data.frame ("hi")` to another data.frame (we'll call it "census") that contains demographic information re each `County`. I had planned to `match()` using `County` names *shared between the two data.tables* and FIPS ID's (geographic federal identifiers).

Before I can proceed with this 2nd step (`match()`), I need to check for "common" county names across States - i.e. there is a Sioux county in both Iowa and North Dakota (as well as Nebraska, it turns out). If I dont find a way around this, I may mistakenly `match()` FIPS ID's and  "census" information.

```
sioux <- hi[hi$County == "Sioux",]

sioux[26:31,1:3]

       State County    Metal.Level
15407    IA  Sioux     Platinum
15408    IA  Sioux Catastrophic
15409    IA  Sioux       Silver
46129    ND  Sioux       Silver
46130    ND  Sioux       Silver
46131    ND  Sioux         Gold
```

It seems that `unique()`, would work well, but given that `County` and `State` are in separate columns, not sure how to specify that I am looking for counties with the same name in different states.

Comment: Why don't you create a new variable which merges both state and county name as `paste0(state,county,sep="-")`... and then perform a unique match... This will create 'Iowa-Sioux' and 'North Dakota-Sioux' as distinct values...

Comment: So it would be `hi$state_county <- paste0(hi$state,hi$county,sep="-")`... and then followed by `unique()`

Comment: any (real) data for testing? could you paste them here with `dput`?

Comment: @Gaurav - I am so sorry for the delay and want to thank you so much. I had to put the project to the side for a period of time, but your recommendation is working out perfectly. Best.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestion provided in the comments a dataframe of unique State, County pairs can be made using the following code.

```
library(dplyr)
sioux %>% distinct(State, County)
```

If you wanted a list across all counties not just a single county you could do the following.

```
#creates a data frame with two county names "Sioux" and "Countyx"
counties <- structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("IA", "ND"), class = "factor"), County = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("  Sioux", " Countyx"), class = "factor"), 
    Metal.Level = structure(c(4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("         Gold", 
    "       Silver", "      Silver", "     Platinum", " Catastrophic"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("State", "County", "Metal.Level"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))


#Find the distinct State Country pairs, then filter out all Country names that only appear 1.

counties %>% distinct(State, County) %>% group_by(County) %>% 
  filter(n()>1)
```